# Перемещение по DIV'ам с помощью кнопок на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Интересует возможность перемещения по элементам DIV с помощью клавиатуры (кнопок: вверх, вниз, вправо, влево). К примеру, при нажатии кнопки вниз, мы будем переходить в DIV, который под нами; при нажатии вправо мы будем переходить в соседний DIV справа и так далее. Интересует именно решение на чистом JS.

Заранее спасибо!

```js
onload = function() {
  for (var j = 0, cl = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), lg = cl.length; j < lg; j++) cl[j].onclick = myFunc;
};

function myFunc(elem) {
  var e = window.event || elem,
    obj = e.target || e.srcElement;
  console.log(obj.innerText);
  obj.style.border = '0.5px solid red';
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == "13") {

    console.log("Enter" + this);
  } else if (event.keyCode == "37") {

    console.log("Left");
  } else if (event.keyCode == "38") {

    console.log("Up");
  } else if (event.keyCode == "39") {

    console.log("Right");
  } else if (event.keyCode == "40") {

    console.log("Down");
  }


}, true);
```

Comment: Сами блоки "сеткой" располагаются, или произвольно?

Comment: @br3t блоки на странице могут быть совершенно разной ширины и высоты, в разных частях страницы и иметь разные стили

Comment: А что насчет вложенных элементов? Давайте хоть примерный html

Comment: @br3t допустим разметка вот такая https://jsfiddle.net/41m1qx28/5/ 
хотя как я понимаю, она может быть совсем любая
P.S. на jsfiddle как то неверно оно работает, но думаю суть ясна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сеточного расположения

```js
var cell = document.querySelectorAll('.box-cell'),
  cell_active = null;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == "13") {

    if (cell_active !== null) {
      cell[cell_active].classList.remove('box-cell--active');
    };

    cell_active = 0;

    cell[cell_active].classList.add('box-cell--active');

  } else if (event.keyCode == "37") {

    if (cell_active !== null && cell_active !== 0 && cell_active !== 3 && cell_active !== 6) {
      cell[cell_active].classList.remove('box-cell--active');

      cell_active = cell_active - 1;

      cell[cell_active].classList.add('box-cell--active');
    };

  } else if (event.keyCode == "38") {

    if (cell_active !== null && cell_active !== 0 && cell_active !== 1 && cell_active !== 2) {
      cell[cell_active].classList.remove('box-cell--active');

      cell_active = cell_active - 3;

      cell[cell_active].classList.add('box-cell--active');
    };

  } else if (event.keyCode == "39") {

    if (cell_active !== null && cell_active !== 2 && cell_active !== 5 && cell_active !== 8) {
      cell[cell_active].classList.remove('box-cell--active');

      cell_active = cell_active + 1;

      cell[cell_active].classList.add('box-cell--active');
    };

  } else if (event.keyCode == "40") {

    if (cell_active !== null && cell_active !== 6 && cell_active !== 7 && cell_active !== 8) {
      cell[cell_active].classList.remove('box-cell--active');

      cell_active = cell_active + 3;

      cell[cell_active].classList.add('box-cell--active');
    };

  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 303px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.box-cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.box-cell--active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
Для введения нажмите Enter!

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
  <div class="box-cell"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Реализация с <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == "13") {
    var div_focus = document.querySelector('.block:focus');
    
    if( div_focus ){
      console.log( div_focus.innerHTML );
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Выберите кнопкой Tab блок и нажмите Enter</p>

<div class="block" tabindex="0">Текст 1</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">Текст 2</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">Текст 3</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">Текст 4</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">Текст 5</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">Текст 6</div>
```

Реализация с помощью кнопок вправо и влево:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block'),
      block_selected = document.querySelector('.block.block--select');
  
  if (event.keyCode == "13") {
    console.log( block_selected.innerHTML )
  } else if (event.keyCode == "37") {
    for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
      if( blocks[i].classList.contains('block--select') && i !== 0){
        blocks[i - 1].classList.add('block--select');
        blocks[i].classList.remove('block--select');
        
        break;
      };
    };
  } else if (event.keyCode == "39") {
    for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
      if( blocks[i].classList.contains('block--select') && i !== blocks.length - 1){
        blocks[i + 1].classList.add('block--select');
        blocks[i].classList.remove('block--select');
        
        break;
      };
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.block--select {color: red;}
```

```html
<p>Выберите кнопкой Tab блок и нажмите Enter</p>

<div class="block">Текст 1</div>
<div class="block">Текст 2</div>
<div class="block block--select">Текст 3</div>
<div class="block">Текст 4</div>
<div class="block">Текст 5</div>
<div class="block">Текст 6</div>
```

Но этот вариант нужно доработать.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересная реализация, но не совсем то, что хотелось бы получить, интересует перемещение по элементам DIV на странице, они могут быть совершенно разной ширины и высоты, в разных частях страницы и иметь разные стили

Comment: @GrumpyCoder, влево и вправо сделать это легко, но вниз и вверх почти нереально сделать. Для переключения между блоками, обычно используют Tab

Comment: понятно, а я то думаю, почему у меня удалось все сделать чтобы оно переходило влево и вправо при нажатии и ничего не получается в других направлениях..

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за ответ и протраченное время, как будет рейтинг выше, обязательно поставлю "плюс" :)

Comment: @GrumpyCoder, можно с помощью Tab показать реализацию :)

Comment: было бы неплохо :)

Comment: верней, было бы очень даже кстати :)

Comment: @GrumpyCoder, Я выложил два. Над вторым надо ещё подумать :)

Comment: спасибо большое за труды, сейчас еще посижу, поразмышляю и поиграюсь с кодом :)

Comment: @GrumpyCoder, давайте) И на счёт Tab, чтобы сделать обратный таб, нажмите Shift+Tab )